# How can I delete the multiple draft mails in Gmail (that I have selected via checkboxes)?

Tags: gmail

I can use the checkbox to select multiple messages, but how can I delete them all in one go? I've tried every option I can see to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they are all drafts, click on **Discard drafts**.

[image]

Otherwise, click on **Move to** and then on **Trash**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the drafts box.  For the draft(s) you wish to delete, tap on the little circle with the figure in it. This then gives a circle and the bin icon appears at top right.  Tap in the circle(s) to get a tick and then tap the bin icon to apply.  Autodidact through trial and error!

Comment: This answer only provides instructions on how to delete each draft, one by one. Is there a more efficient way to delete the contents of the entire “Draft” folder without having to go through each one? I’m utilizing the latest Gmail app (iOS) and I’m having difficulty finding a definitive answer to this question. TIA for your help. Edit for clarification: I was responding to “BOB”. I apologize for any confusion I may have initially caused. I realize now that this belongs in the comments of Bob’s answer, but Im hoping someone will see this and might be able to help me, so I’ll leave it here.

Answer (score -2):

Do the discard draft one. It works

Comment: Please don't add "this works" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//webapps.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Web Applications way of saying thank you.